# See if an instance method exists via respondsToSelector

Tags: ios, selector

I've got a bunch of keys and values in an array and want to find out wether I can savely call

```
[self setValue:obj forKey:key];
```

for my class. For the time being I use the following method to see wether a setter method exists.

```
    [userDefaults enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *firstCapChar = [[key substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString];
        NSString *cappedString = [key stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:firstCapChar];
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([[@"set" stringByAppendingString:cappedString] stringByAppendingString:@":"]);
        if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [self setValue:obj forKey:key];
        }
    }];
```

I'm curious if there is an even easier way doing that kind of check.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question because `setObject:forKey:` is not the same as `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: Self here relates to an NSObject with iVars of different type (NSInteger/NSString/NSDictionary). Though it works as expected I'm not sure wether it is correct. I myself provide setter and getter methods.  So setObject:forKey wont work here.

Comment: My point is that you start your question by saying you want to test for `setObject:forKey:` but then you actually implement a different test.